# how to send dictionary<int,string> from server side (C# code) to client side (javascript code) with callback

Tags: javascript, c#, callback

I try to send dictionary from C# and server side to client side and java script.
 I wrote this code in c# (my dictionary has valid data)

```
public static dictionary<int,string> codInfo = new dictionary<int,string>();
public dictionary<int,string> CallbackMethod_GetCoding(int level)
{
    return CodingInfo;
}
```

then I receive it in javascript with this method;

```
var CallbackMethods =
    {
        GetCoding: function (FailedHandler, SuccessHandler) {

            Page.ShowLoading();

            begin_CallbackMethod_GetCoding(stemp, function (ASyncResult) {

                try {

                    var Result = end_CallbackMethod_GetCoding(ASyncResult);

                    if (SuccessHandler)
                        SuccessHandler(Result);

                } catch (ex) {

                    if (FailedHandler)
                        FailedHandler();
                }
                finally { Page.HideLoading(); }
            });
        }
```

Comment: please elaborate,  your client side code is not understandable with server code, we can't relate things in air

Comment: I invoke this call back with some code like this

    function initializeVar() {
            CallbackMethods.GetCoding(function () {
                Page.ShowGenericError("vldt_100");
            },
           function (Result) {
              
               SetPageValue(Result);
           });

        }

Comment: I send my data as a string but I couldn't send as a dictionary.
NObody knows!!!